# Backbone Click Event On Button Not Working

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

https://jsfiddle.net/2j0bw7yy/

If you look at the jsfiddle link above you can see a very basic Backbone app.

Everything works except this line:

```
events: {
    "click button": "updatePoints"
},

updatePoints: function() {
    alert("aaa");
    return this;
},
```

When I click the button, the updatePoints function is not called. Nothing happens.

The error message in the console is quite cryptic:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Comment: don't use the minified versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using jQuery 1.6.x. Backbone requires at least 1.7.x.

In the backbone code, this was failing since 1.6.x does not have `.off`

```
undelegateEvents: function() {
  this.$el.off('.delegateEvents' + this.cid);
  return this;
},
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2j0bw7yy/1/